# Produce client deliverable artifacts

Tags: flyway

very new to flyway and have added it to my project using flyway-maven-plugin.
using oracle 11g db.

Looks to be great for database versioning in a development environment but can anyone tell me:

- how to use to produce database create/upgrade artifacts that i can send to a customer.
  we have packages, data, ddls etc (that would be nice inside an installer)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not the official support forum for any product. See [this help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) for the guidelines Flyway should be following when sending you here.

Answer (score 0):

You can always bundle the migrations directly with the Flyway Command-line tool and send that.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Axel. That piece wasn't actually clear to me from flyway documentation. i'll certainly look again, but, do you have a link to an example of that by any chance?